# Comparing next/previous element in a Key/Value Pair within a For..In loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

**I built a K/V pair array based on some values.**

Here is the data structure:

```
var selItemsDimArray = []

selItemsDimArray.push({
    'examinedElem': multiselected[i],
    'x': bb.x,
    'y': bb.y,
    'x2': (bb.x + bb.width),
    'y2': (bb.y + bb.height),
    'height': bb.height,
    'width': bb.width
});
```

I would like to iterate over the elements and compare the next record in the selItemsDim array with the *currently-iterated-over* element.

**> The calculation is this:**

> Get difference between *currently-iterated-over* and the *next element*
>   in terms of distance.
>
> ( *next*('x2') - *current*('x') )

If I had a simple array I could just do [i+1] - [i], where [i+1] is the next element and [i] is the current.

Here is a sample For..In loop that I use. How can I adjust it so it does the above?

```
   for (var key in selItemsDimArray) {
   var obj = selItemsDimArray[key];
   for (var prop in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
       if (obj['x']<smallestFound){
        xOfCurrent = obj['x'];
       }
      }
   }
```

Comment: `selItemsDimArray` is array so you can loop by index like `for(var i=0;i<selItemsDimArray.length-1;i++ ){var obj=selItemsDimArray[i]; var next=selItemsDimArray[i+1];  ...}`

Comment: yep that hits the spot,completely missed that, thanks

Comment: See [Why is using `for…in` on arrays such a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572). If `i` (or `key`) was an integer, the `i+1` would easily work.